# HTML5 <video> does not play on Android emulator 4.0

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I try play a video in html5 page on Android emulator 0f version 4.0, and I found that the screen
is black(can not show the video picture) and the audio play normally. I have searching the Internet for a couple of hours, still I can't get the answer I want. Can someone tell me reason or the solutions? By the way, I'm sorry for my poor English. Code is listed as below:

```
<div id="CHPlayer">
  <video id="video" usemap="#Map" poster="./sources/1/t2.jpg" xmlsrc="./sources/1/t2.xml">
   <source src="./sources/1/t2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img id="insertBar" src="./sources/1/t2.jpg" usemap="#Map" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your video fit under the android requirements? Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Also check under the initial grid for the encoding requirments.

If it is compatible then you also may have to make sure it isn't the emulator.

Comment: Thanks very much for TheChristopher.Yeah, the problem is caused by the encoding of the movie.

Comment: TheChristopher: What would it look like to "make sure it isn't the emulator"?